# Linearization of arbitrary equation

Tags: calculus

If we define linearization of equation as here:

http://academic.macewan.ca/physlabs/Linearization.pdf,

is it possible to linearize any arbitrary equation?

If so, is there an algorithm, I could code let's say in Mathematica, that could always take some equation and output, equation for $x$ axis, and equation for $y$ axis?

Comment: Do you want to do linearization in 2 dimensions, 3 dimensions, or "n" dimensions?

Comment: Just $2D$, because we must linearize equation, draw linear fit to data and get quantities from the slope in our reports. I know, that there are better numerical methods, but we have to do it this way (high school). I' m writing code in Mathematica, that will automatically write LaTex lab reports for me including graphs, tables, results with errors,... @DavidWhite

Comment: Then Richard Myers definitely gave you a very good answer.  Use a numeric derivative to get F', and if you need the equation of the line that runs through the point that you linearize about, use the point-slope form of the equation of a line.  And BTW, what you are learning is VERY useful in real life if you want to do a STEM job, so it would be a good idea to file your work away for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always possible to linearize equations (given some technical requirements), but not always useful to do so. To understand the how and why, note that any equation in $x$ can be put into the form $F(x)=0$. If the equation has more than one variable in it, then $F$ would depend on these other variables as well. The simplest way to see that all equations can be put into this form is to write the equation as $(something)=(something else)$ and move the right hand side to the left: $(something)-(something else)=0$ so $F=(something)-(something else)$.

Given this, and assuming $F$ is an analytic function (meaning its Taylor series exists), then we may Taylor expand about any point $x_0$:
$$
0=F(x)=F(x_0)+F^\prime(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}F^{\prime\prime}(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+\cdots.
$$
Truncating this expansion at first order (it is interesting to think about when this is reasonable to do) we would find
$$
F(x_0)+F^\prime(x_0)(x-x_0)=0
$$

but since $x_0$ is some fixed number, $F(x_0)$ and $F^\prime(x_0)$ are constants with respect to $x$, and so this is a linear equation. We would say that this is the linearization of the original equation.

I will note that what I have described here shows linearization to, in general, be an *approximation* to the true equation, and hence any solutions thereof will only be approximate.

The link in the question only considers examples where $F(x)$ is an invertible function. In this special case, there exists a function $F^{-1}(x)$ such that $F^{-1}(F(x))=x$. For example if $F(x)=\ln x$, then $F^{-1}(x)=e^x$. With this we are able to apply $F^{-1}$ to both sides of $F(x)=0$ and obtain
$$
F^{-1}(0)=F^{-1}(F(x))=x,
$$
which is not only linear, but is in fact the solution.